# Facebook Debugger complains about Title property

Tags: html, facebook

I'm working on a site and trying to correct all problems I see from the Facebook debugger. It's complaining that the following warnings should be fixed:

> Objects of this type do not allow properties named
>   'http://purl.org/dc/terms/title'.
>
> Parser Mismatched Metadata:   The parser's result for this metadata did
>   not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data
>   being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a
>   property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given
>   property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not
>   seen in the parsed result: 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/title'

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here is the site to my temp dev site:
http://drupal.inadaydevelopment.com/blog/blog.cfm/aid/631/Waikiki-goes-off-with-Town-and-Country-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is solved if you disable the module RDF